# How is this function surjective? (Double Counting)

Tags: combinatorics, functions, chessboard

> We call a positive integer $n$ "good" if and only if , in a $6 \cdot 6$ checkerboard , no matter how we put $n$ $1 \cdot 2$ dominoes in the board, there will be a space for another domino (There will be a $1 \cdot 2$ or $2 \cdot 1$ space). Find the maximum "good" integer.

I think the answer is $11$. Here's my work.

### Section 1 : 12 isn't "good"

[image].

As you can see, this is a figure that shows $12$ isn't "good".

### Section 2 : 11 is "good" (Where I'm stuck)

So, I learn this and my teacher solution is as follows,

First, assume some counterexample exists.

Let $A$ be sets of all spaces in the upper $5 \cdot 6$ board.

Let $B$ be sets of all spaces in the lower $1 \cdot 6$ board.

If $|B| \geq 4$ ; there will be two spaces that are connected , a contradiction.

So, $|B| \leq 3$

Since there are a total of $36 - 2(11) = 14$ spaces.

Hence, $|A| \geq 11$.

Let $C$ be sets of all dominoes that are fully included in the lower $5 \cdot 6$ board.

Now, assume that , there exists some space in $A$ that there is no domino below it. This will create a $1 \cdot 2$ space which we can put another domino. A contradiction.

So, there will always be a domino below a space in $A$.

We define a function $f : A \rightarrow C$ such that $f(t) = $ domino below $t$ $\space$ $\forall t \in A$

Now, my teacher says that this function is bijective , so $|C| = |A| \geq 11$. But maximum number of dominos is $11$ , $|C| = 11$. But if we consider the upper $1 \cdot 6$ board, we can easily put a domino in it. Hence, a contradiction.

So,$11$ is "good".

### My question

From Section 2, I think I can show the injective part,

Let $f(a_1) = f(a_2) =$ domino "m"

Case I : "m" is horizontal.

Now, if $a_1$ is the left space above "m" and $a_2$ is the right space of "m" , we can put another domino above "m", a contradiction. So, $a_1 = a_2$.

Case II : "m" is vertical. This case is obvious.

Thus, $f$ is injective.

I know we can finish the problem using only injectivity and change $|C| = |A|$ to $|C| \geq |A|$ and finish the problem.

But I can't figure out how $f$ is surjective. Can anyone give me a hint or a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the maximum "good" integer for a $6\times 6$ board is 11.

This [paper](https://www.bjmc.lu.lv/fileadmin/user_upload/lu_portal/projekti/bjmc/Contents/8_4_02_Cibulis.pdf) deals with  the minimum number $D(m,n)$ of dominoes on a $m\times n$ board needed to prevent placement of another domino.
In Theorem 1, the authors show the following general inequality: for $m,n\geq 2$
$$D(m,n)\geq H(m,n)$$
where $H(m,n)=mn-2D(m,n)$ is the number of *holes*. It follows that
$$D(m,n)\geq\left\lceil \frac{mn}{3}\right\rceil$$
In your case, the above inequality says that $D(6,6)\geq 12$.

See also [oeis.org/A280984](https://oeis.org/A280984) as a reference.